# Questions about third-party library(oat++) configuration in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, oat++

As a beginner, I want to use [oat++](https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp) as a third-party library in visual studio, but I encountered some configuration problems.

First I downloaded the source file of the oat++ project and opened it in visual studio and `cmake` and `install`.

Then I created a new project in visual studio and started running the [first example](https://oatpp.io/docs/start/step-by-step/#api-low-level-components-overview) of the official website.

First of all, it need to configure the preprocessing, I will configure the Include directory first.
What I did is:(my project name is web4)

- `Project` -> `Web4 properties` -> `configuration properties` -> `VC++ Directories`
- set the `Include Directories` include `C:\Users\13925\Documents\cpp\oatpp\out\install\x64-Debug\include\oatpp-1.2.5\oatpp`

That is great. The compiler can find the `#include "file"`

After that I'm having trouble，An error occurred when I tried to compile.

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAStartup referenced in function....
```

[image: Error]

By searching for information, it is found that the cause of this problem is that the related library is not included.
But I tried the online method and it didn’t solve the problem，so ask for help here.

The online approach is like this:

1. `Project` -> `Web4 properties` -> `configuration properties` -> `VC++ Directories`
2. set the `Library Directories` include `C:\Users\13925\Documents\cpp\oatpp\out\install\x64-Debug\lib\oatpp-1.2.5`

In `C:\Users\13925\Documents\cpp\oatpp\out\install\x64-Debug\lib\oatpp-1.2.5` has three files:`oatpp.lib`、`oatpp-test.lib`and a `.h`files.

[image]

3. `Project` -> `Web4 properties` -> `configuration properties` -> `Linker` -> `Input`
4. set `Additional Dependencies` include `oatpp.lib` and `oatpp-test.lib`

[image]
[image]

Compile after completing the above four steps and find that the problem is still not solved.
And the problen still `unresolved external symbol`.

I would be very grateful if you are willing to help.

Comment: `WSAStartup` requires you also add the library `Ws2_32.lib` see __Remarks__ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup

Comment: Maybe try the x32 configuration? This solved my issues many times.

Comment: Try auto install using vcpkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, the problem is you are not linking against the Ws2_32.lib library. To fix this you could try to add that to your additional dependencies tab of linker/Input settings for your project. And you could also try to add: `#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")`

Best Regards,

Jeanine